# Split one object into different uv sets for a more detailed texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I want one joined object to have multiple UV sets, each set corresponding to a particular part of the object. Then I want to export the object to Substance Painter and select a UV set to paint on. How do I do that? And if that is not possible, what should I do to be able to apply a texture to an object and the texture covers a particular part of the object and then I apply another and it covers it's part?

Comment: you can create several UV maps (see in the Object Data panel > UV Maps), then in your material create an Input > UV Map node. That way you can assign a big PNG to the parts you want. Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is simply to have a more detailed texture, then the relative sizes of your UV islands shouldn't matter - rather, the resolution of your image texture is important.

You certainly can map your texture across multiple images like moonboots said, and each of those images can afford to be smaller while still maintaining a highly detailed whole, but if you have everything unwrapped onto a large enough image you'll basically have the same result.

What resolution are you using for your textures? 2k? 4k? It's not unheard of to have 8k+ textures these days.

ETA:

Otherwise, I'm guessing your objective is just to keep these parts of your texture separate? I believe Substance has functionality for masks if you can't separate the meshes.

Comment: Somehow I haven't considered increasing the resolution